# overrideUserInterfaceStyle on Mac Catalyst not effecting the Toolbar / Title bar?

Tags: uikit, mac-catalyst

I'm giving my users a way to configure the dark mode style of an application. I achieve this by setting the overrideUserInterfaceStyle property of the windows on every WindowScene of the application.

This works on iPad and iPhone, but on Catalyst the toolbar area of the window does not change style. It's always the same as the system.

Is there a different technique required to change the interface style of a Catalyst application?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?